# Creating analogue of Sketchfab

Tags: 3d, three.js, rendering

Our challenge is to create an analogue Sketchfab on its website. To be able to view the virtual object model. Does anyone know what technologies are used to Sketchfab and that required to implement such a project?

Answer (score 1):

Sketchfab uses the OSGJS WebGL framework, not three.js: http://osgjs.org/

Comment: The project page has moved to: https://cedricpinson.github.io/osgjs-website/